# SQL Server query with sums from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have 3 tables that I am trying to report from that are all related but have a different number of records. I want a summary line for each order that shows job description, total price and total cost.

My tables are a follows:

Prices

```
| Order | Line # | Description  | Price |
+-------+--------+--------------+-------+
| 1     | 1      | Line 1 job#1 | 100   |
| 1     | 2      | Line 2 job#1 | 30    |
| 2     | 1      | Line 1 job#2 | 100   |
| 3     | 1      | Line 1 job#3 | 75    |
```

Cost lines

```
| Order | Line # | Cost record | Cost |
+-------+--------+-------------+------+
| 1     | 1      | 1           | 80   |
| 1     | 2      | 2           | 80   |
| 1     | 2      | 3           | 50   |
| 2     | 1      | 1           | 75   |
| 3     | 1      | 1           | 50   |
| 3     | 1      | 2           | 50   |
```

Order Header

```
| Order | Description | Sales Person |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
| 1     | Order # 1   | 1            |
| 1     | Order #2    | 2            |
| 1     | Order #3    | 1            |
```

I keep getting way to many associated rows. I've been trying subqueries with sums but I just can't get it to work.

Expected result:

```
 | Order | Description | Price | Cost | Sales Person |
 +-------+-------------+-------+------+--------------+
 | 1     | Order #1    | 130   | 210  | 1            | 
 | 2     | Order #2    | 100   | 75   | 2            |
 | 3     | Order #3    | 75    | 100  | 1            |
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Where are the orders stored? I'd assumed in `Order Header`, but there's only one order in it (with three different descriptions and two different sales people), so this cannot be it... And why are there two records in `Cost lines` with the same `Line #` for order 1?

Comment: What's the specific database engine? (e.g. Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)

Comment: I would assume the "price" should be higher than the "cost". However, the price of order #1 is only $130 (100 + 30) while the cost is $210 (80 + 80 + 50). How does that make sense?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.  One would like for price to be higher than cost, but that is not always the case.  My goal here isn't to get behind the business rules, but to generate the proper SQL syntax.  I can write individual queries and get the sums from the tables, but when I join them I am getting too many results.

Comment: To answer sticky bit, there will in our line of business often be many cost relations for just just 1 sale line item.  There could be purchase costs as well as labor costs, etc.

Comment: The expected result would be | Order | Description | Price | Cost | Sales Person |
|-------|-------------|-------|------|--------------|
| 1     | Order #1    | 130   | 210  | 1            |
| 2     | Order #2    | 100   | 75   | 2            |
| 3     | Order #3    | 75    | 100  | 1            |

Comment: @BuddyPeacock: Adding code or tabular text to a question in the comments is hard to read. Please consider to edit your question, if you want to add something, especially code or tabular text. I edited the question for you this time, but please remember that for the future.

Comment: @BuddyPeacock: No, that didn't answer my question. But I now think you just made a mistake in your post there an entered three times `1` instead of `1`, `2`, `3` in the first column of `Order Header`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is a mistake in your sample data and the first column should read `1`, `2` and `3` rather than three times `1`. At least your desired result makes that seem very plausible.

Join the costs and prices to the orders and then `GROUP BY` the orders and calculate the sum for the costs and prices.

```
 SELECT o.[Order],
        o.[Description],
        sum(p.[Price]) [Price],
        sum(c.[Cost]) [Cost],
        o.[Sales Person]
        FROM [Order Header] o
             LEFT JOIN [Cost lines] c
                       ON c.[Order] = o.[Order]
             LEFT JOIN [Prices] p
                       ON p.[Order] = o.[Order]
        GROUP BY o.[Order],
                 o.[Description],
                 o.[Sales Person];
```

Comment: Thank you sticky bit. No they are all for Order 1,  I probably should have added a unique primary key for each.  This is just sample data as the real database is too extensive to load here.  Let me try this logic though and see what happens.

Comment: What is happening is the actual sum Price is being multiplied by the number of associated cost rows and the sum Cost is being multiplied by the number of associated Price rows. Attached here is my actual syntax from my real DB.  Perhaps this might help you see where I'm goofing up.

Comment: I can't add the statement as it is too long.  I will add it in 2 pieces

Comment: Well I've got to modify my script as I have "@" varables and the system thinks that I am trying to tag too many individuals

Comment: SELECT  J.job_id, J.sub_job_id, J.sales_rep_id, SUM(A.Price) AS Price, A.entered_by, A.description, A.update_date, SUM(P.cost_production) AS 'AA Cost', SUM(P.hours) AS 'AA Hours', J.prod_div_id

FROM job J
 LEFT JOIN  alterations A
  ON A.job_id = J.job_id AND A.sub_job_id = J.sub_job_id AND (A.update_date = @StartDate) AND J.prod_div_id = '10'
 LEFT JOIN productiontran P

Comment: ON P.work_type_id = 'AA' 
  AND ((P.date_actual = @StartDate) OR (a.update_date = @StartDate))
  AND  J.prod_div_id = '10'
  AND (P.job_id = A.job_id AND P.sub_job_id = A.sub_job_id)
  AND (P.job_id = J.job_id AND P.sub_job_id = J.sub_job_id)
WHERE work_type_id ='AA'
 AND ((P.date_actual = @StartDate) OR (A.update_date = @StartDate))
 AND J.prod_div_id = '10'
 AND (P.job_id = J.job_id AND P.sub_job_id = J.sub_job_id)
 AND (A.job_id = J.job_id AND A.sub_job_id = J.sub_job_id)
 GROUP BY J.job_id, J.sub_job_id, J.sales_rep_id, A.entered_by, A.description, A.update_date, J.prod_div_id